# Connecting/directing user to its page

Tags: php, html

I just want to make my web like facebook, twitter, etc. where every user has its own page.
**Is there any easy way to do it without bothering internet security.**

From my search on net, I thought  php, mysqli, html5,CSS is a way to do. But i don't know how can it be done. It is my first try....

I made database and put

uid..username...password..Uurl(Userurl)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Erstellungszeit: 11. Jul 2016 um 14:12
-- Server Version: 5.6.17
-- PHP-Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `demos`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur fÃ¼r Tabelle `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Uurl` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Daten fÃ¼r Tabelle `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`uid`, `username`, `password`, `Uurl`) VALUES
(2, 'test', '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6', 'de2bef8b980f92e688c369c45af82584'),
(3, 'demo1', 'fe01ce2a7fbac8fafaed7c982a04e229', '082b82c6e8fcfba13ac0abebcd391a5e');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connection.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

    $error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $error = "Both fields are required.";
        }else
        {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            // To protect from MySQL injection
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
            $password = md5($password);

            //Check username and password from database
            $sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            //If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
            //Otherwise echo error.

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // Initializing Session
                header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            }else
            {
                $error = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }

        }
    }

?>
```

I think I need to change ...

```
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // Initializing Session
                header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To USER PAGE....
```

But I don't know how can I do it.

Any help? or better idea? I can post more code if required...

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Your are using `MySQLi`, *great!*. Now start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)!